# jquery based on a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qualtrics

I am working on a survey platform. By default I have a footer that shows up in all survey pages. I need the footer to display only on the first display page. In order to do this I am attaching this jQuery to all pages where I want the footer hidden:

```
jQuery("#Footer").hide();
```

The issue I am having now is that based on a link condition, the first page of the survey can be `page1` or `page2`. This means. I have 2 scenarios:

1. I access the survey using `link1`. This should start on `pag1`, `pag2`, `pag3`. The footer is displayed only on `pag1` and is hidden by jQuery on the subsequent pages.
2. I access the survey using `link2`. This should start display `pag2` first. The footer is not displayed and is hidden by the jQuery I applied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this script to `pag1` and `pag2`.
I assume your URL to be something like : `link1/**/**/pag1` or `link2/**/**/pag2`

```
var pageURL = window.location.href;

if((pageURL.includes("link1") && pageURL.includes("pag1")) || 
   (pageURL.includes("link2") && pageURL.includes("pag2")))
{
    jQuery("#Footer").show();
}
else
{
    jQuery("#Footer").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Approach 1**

You can show/hide footer based on URL, specifically the page name

> **Approach 2**

you can add a query string parameter and add different values based on adapted route to Page2, then  based on query string parameter values you can make decision to show/hide footer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support.
The JS code is ok and works. The problem was where the code was being included within the platform. I know learn that code gets executed differently depending on the ref. it is included in.
This was an internal issue. Nothing specific to the code.